# PHP contact for (405 Not Allowed)

Tags: php, html

I have my HTML contact form and my PHP post. With my website Live... when submitting the form I'm lead to a "405 Not Allowed" page. I'm very new to PHP and I'm lost at this point.

Following some of the online tutorials... there is an index.php. I'm guessing this is where the page goes to when submit is clicked.

contact.html:

```
<form method="post" class="contact-form" action="contactform.php">
                <div class="form_settings">
                    <p><span>Subject</span><input class="contact" type="text" name="subject" value="" /></p>
                    <p><span>Name</span><input class="contact" type="text" name="name" value="" /></p>
                    <p><span>Email Address</span><input class="contact" type="text" name="mail" value="" /></p>
                    <p><span>Message</span><textarea class="contact textarea" rows="8" cols="50" name="message"></textarea></p>
                    <div class="button">
                        <p style="padding-top: 15px"><span>&nbsp;</span><input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

contactform.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$mailTo = "xxxxxxxx@yahoo.com";
$headers = "Form: ".$mailFrom;
$txt = "You have received an E-mail from ".$name.".\n\n".$message;

mail($mailTo, $subject , $message, $headers);
header("Location: index.php?mailsend");
```

index.php

```
     <?php 
echo "Hello world!"; 
?>
```

Comment: Your `contactform.php` code is fine (with the exception of `Form` instead of `From`). This will likely cause a crash when attempting to send the mail. You'll also want to check that the other `$_POST` fields are set. However, the main problem seems as though your webhost is not allowing automatic redirects (which is happening due to `header()`). `index.php` has HTML inside of PHP, which will require an `echo`, which may also be causing some problems.

Comment: The HTML in index.php is not valid PHP code. It needs to be echoed or printed or you could simply omit the `<?php` and `?>` if you are not performing any PHP operations. That probably doesn't explain the 405 error though (would likely be 500). Which page gives you the error? Does it ever make it to index.php?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I went ahead and added an echo. "(with the exception of Form instead of From)"... Am I changing the Form to From?

Comment: Hey 405 errors is difficult to handle but i suggest to replace your method in the html with `action="/contactform.php"` try it